# Code still running despite if statement?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, if-statement, input

```
                echo '<form method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="selector3">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="submit3">
                                  </form>';

                                  if (!empty($_POST['selector3'])) {

                        $eventsquery = mysql_query("
                            SELECT studentid, statusid, timestamp, elapsed
                            FROM events
                            WHERE studentid = '$name'
                            AND statusid = '$_POST['selector3']'
                            ORDER BY timestamp DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                            ")
                            or die("Error querying database ".mysql_error()); }
```

It runs the code in the if statment even though selector 3 isn't set!

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['selector3']);` output?

Comment: @Amal Murali it outputs undefined index

Answer (score 0):

You could try using isset instead of empty.

```
if (isset($_POST["selector3"])) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That must mean that `$_POST["selector3"]` has a value. So it isn't as empty as you thought it was. You are posting to get to this page, can you check the selector3 value before you post?

Answer (score 0):

The code works as expected here.i.e. The query doesn't get executed when $_POST['selector3'] is empty.

However, there was a syntax error in the query. It was confused by the $_POST['selector3'].

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
$name = '';
echo '<form method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="selector3">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="submit3">
                                  </form>';

                                  if (!empty($_POST['selector3'])) {

                        $eventsquery = mysql_query("
                            SELECT studentid, statusid, timestamp, elapsed
                            FROM events
                            WHERE studentid = '$name'
                            AND statusid = '{$_POST['selector3']}'
                            ORDER BY timestamp DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                            ")
                            or die("Error querying database ".mysql_error()); }
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```